# Quantized Convolution Layer Operation in TensorflowLite

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I want to understand the basic operation done in a convolution layer of a quantized model in TensorflowLite.

As a baseline, I chose a pretrained Tensorflow model, [EfficientNet-lite0-int8](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/tree/master/models/official/efficientnet/lite) and used a sample image to serve as input for model's inference. Thereinafter, I managed to extract the output tensor of the first fused ReLU6 Convolution Layer and **compared** this output **with that of my custom python implementation** on [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4952f981be07b8bf508f8226f83c10cdafa3f0c4/tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/internal/reference/reference_ops.h#L248-L314).

The deviation between the two tensors was large and something that I cannot explain is that Tensorflow's output tensor was not between the range of [0,6] as expected (I expected that because of the fused ReLU6 layer in the Conv layer).

**Could you please provide me with a more detailed description of a quantized fused Relu6 Conv2D layer's operation in TensorflowLite?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After, studying carefully Tensorflow's github repository I found kernel_util.cc file and CalculateActivationRangeUint8 function. So using this function, I managed to understand why quantized fused ReLu6 Conv2D layer's output tensor is not clipped between [0, 6] but between [-128, 127] values. For the record, I managed to implement a Conv2D layer's operation in Python with some simple steps.

- Firstly, you got to take layer's parameters(kernel, bias, scales, offsets) using interpreter.get_tensor_details() command and calculate output_multiplier using GetQuantizedConvolutionMultipler and QuantizeMultiplierSmallerThanOne functions.
- After that, subtract input offset from the input layer before padding it and implement a simple convolution.
- Later, you need to use MultiplyByQuantizedMultiplierSmallerThanOne function that uses SaturatingRoundingDoublingHighMul and RoundingDivideByPOT from gemmlowp/fixedpoint.h library.
- Finally, add output_offset to the result and clip it using the values taken from CalculateActivationRangeUint8 function.

[Link of the issue on project's github page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53370)